# Best Steps for replacing in sql files

Tags: c#, .net, regex, sql-server-2005

I need to update all varchar to nvarchar, text to ntext and char to nchar in some 300 .sql files stored on my disk. These files include stored procedures, triggers, functions, views etc. What is the best approach to achieve this.

Comment: Because of the issues already stated in comments to answers (possibility of the words occurring within literals), it seems that you would need to parse the files in order to identify the types needing change.

Comment: There's a .NET wrapper for the excellent Scintilla source code editor control. After setting the language to SQL, there's a method you can use to query the exact syntactic role of the text selected, like keyword, string literal, etc. If you have so many files this might be worth looking into.

Comment: yep.. parsing is the way to go... could you suggest some way on how to go on with the parsing approach!!!

Comment: Here it is: http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Scintilla does the parsing for you, no need to do it manually!

Comment: I didn't try, but since type names and object and column names are all just identifiers, I doubt that Scintilla will be able to tell them apart. I does require quite an in-depth knowledge of the language in order to succeed (think of the special `CAST` and `CONVERT` functions etc.).

Comment: I quite liked the idea of scintilla.. need to look into creating a full fledged tool though. Thanks neo for the idea.. If you could have posted this as an answer I would have accepted this!!!

Comment: Chinjoo, try it out, I still believe that my concern in the comment above is valid regarding Scintilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want the safe way, you'd need to use a parser which actually understands the structure and only replaces these occurenses which do match.

I'm not sure if the effort to dive into it is worth it, but you could code something yourself. You could try and see if an opensource T-SQL parser can handle your files; one is part of the opensource [bsn ModuleStore versioning toolset](http://code.google.com/p/bsn-modulestore/).

Answer (score 0):

`.sql` files are nothing more than text files anyhow. I would iterate through the files and replace these string while parsing.

Comment: What if a string constant contains the word "text"? Pretty common in my opinion. You won't want to replace inside comments either. You need something more syntax-aware than simple search & replace.

Comment: Also there may be Column names called Text. in that case also you should not replace those.

Comment: Find out how you can make sure to replace the correct instance of 'text'. Let's say when you've encountered a 'CREATE TABLE', for instance, you probably can state that the 'text' met there will be a data type. Otherwise, for only 300 files, it might not be worthy and you'd better do it manually while performing manual `Find...Replace`.

Comment: @Chinjoo: Agreed. And that is one of the best reason not to name a database object the same as a keyword.